# How handle button click jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to catch click event in jquery and this is my HTML code:

```
<input type="button" id="aggiungiDomande" value="+">
```

and this is my Jquery code:

```
$('#aggiungiDomande').on('click',function(){
alert("HI");
});
```

I think I'm wroing something because I show nothing. Anyone can help me?

Comment: It is working fine. If you didn't put your code in `$(document).ready(function() { //code }` See https://jsfiddle.net/harishkommuri/yb4yp29z/

Comment: Have you wrapped your javascript code into `$(document).ready()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this :

```
$(document).on('click', '#aggiungiDomande',function(){
    alert("HI");
});
```

If your button does not exist when your code is executed, no event wil get bound to it. You can read more about event binding here : http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
$("document").ready(function(){
$('#aggiungiDomande').on('click',function(){
alert("HI");
});
});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<button id = "aggiungiDomande">Click me</button><br><br>

</body>
</html>
```